# Como fazer join com múltiplas tabelas?

Tags: sql, mysql

Eu tenho 4 tabelas eles já estão com foreign key.

```
aluno:
id
matricula
username
curso_id          // referencia a id_cursos da tabela cursos, coluna id_cursos.
```

---

```
cursos: 
id_cursos
nome_cursos
```

---

```
modulos:
id_modulos
nome_modulos
cursos_id         //faz referencia a tabela cursos, coluna id_cursos.
```

---

```
materias:
id_materias
nome_materias
modulos_id       // faz referencia a tabela modulos, coluna id_modulos.
```

---

na tabela aluno tem 2 registro:

---

```
id | matricula | username | curso_id.<br>
1  | 12345678  | Usuario1 | 1
```

---

```
id | matricula | username | curso_id.<br>
2  | 12344321  | Usuario2 | 2
```

---

Eu quero retorna todas as tabelas mais só as colunas que estão relacionada com o aluno coluna curso_id 1, exemplo, um aluno tem um curso, um curso tem vários módulos, um módulo tem várias mateiras, então tem que retornar nesta ordem, aluno selecionado faz curso de Administração, então retorna os módulos do curso de Administração e as matérias dos módulos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe estas duas formas:

USANDO JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM ALUNO AS AL JOIN CURSO AS CS ON AL.curso_id = CS.id_cursos JOIN  MODULOS AS MD ON CS.id_cursos = MD.cursos_id JOIN MATERIAIS AS MT ON MT.modulos_id = MD.id_modulos
```

E usando WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM ALUNO, CURSOS, MODULOS, MATERIAIS WHERE ALUNO.curso_id =  CURSOS.id_cursos AND MODULOS.cursos_id = CURSOS.id_cursos AND MATERIAIS.modulos_id = MODULOS.id_modulos
```