# Como utilizar dois join seguidos SQL

Tags: sql, query, join, count, sum

Como posso utilizar dois joins seguidos, sendo que o segundo utilizará os dados da tabela gerada pelo primeiro? Quero que ele relacione os join pelos mesmos dados, onde, no primeiro join ele une os dados da tabela A com os da tabela B apenas quando RG e CPF for igual, então eu quero alterar os demais valores que não "batam" entre as tabelas para a string "ANONIMO", para só então realizar outro join que resultaria em todos os dados da tabela A aparecendo (em diferentes "casa do_amigo" e contando quantas vezes cada uma das casas aparecem). Este código abaixo não está funcionando completamente, pois existem dados que não estão aparecendo.

```
     SELECT amigo, casa do_amigo, 
  COUNT (casa do_amigo) as números_de_casas_do_amigo
FROM
  (
  SELECT amigo, casa do_amigo, 
    IF (part3 = Classificacao, Classificacao, "ANONIMO") as parte3,
    IF (part4 = Sub_Classificacao, Sub_Classificacao, "ANONIMO") as parte4
    FROM 
      (
      SELECT *
      FROM 
        ( 
          SELECT amigo, tipo_de_residencia, bairro do_amigo,  endereço do_amigo,
          SPLIT (endereço do_amigo, '\\') [SAFE_ORDINAL (1)] as part1,
          SPLIT (endereço do_amigo, '\\') [SAFE_ORDINAL (2)] as part2,
          SPLIT (endereço do_amigo, '\\') [SAFE_ORDINAL (3)] as part3,
          SPLIT (endereço do_amigo, '\\') [SAFE_ORDINAL (4)] as part4,
          SPLIT (endereço do_amigo, '\\') [SAFE_ORDINAL (5)] as part5,
          SPLIT (endereço do_amigo, '\\') [SAFE_ORDINAL (6)] as part6
          FROM `codes.enderecoamigo.tabela1`
          WHERE tipo_de_residencia = "CASA" AND amigo = "roger"
        ) AS A
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
          SELECT *
          FROM `codes.enderecoamigo.tabela2` 
        ) AS B
        ON A.part3 = B.rg  AND A.part4 = B.cpf)) AS C
JOIN
        (
          SELECT RG as Reg_geral, cpf as Cad_PF, casa_do_amigo as moradia
          FROM `codes.enderecoamigo.tabela2` 
        ) AS D
ON C.parte3 = D.Reg_geral  AND C.parte4 = D.Cad_PF
GROUP by amigo, casa_do_amigo
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer join com múltiplas tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252470/como-fazer-join-com-m%c3%baltiplas-tabelas)

Comment: já pesquisou no site? tem várias perguntas sobre joins aqui, como essa por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313399/57220